# How to get specific elements and subelements from lists stored inside a data frame built with tidyr package?

Tags: r, list, dplyr, tidyr, segment

I'm doing a piecewise linear regression within each group on a data frame. For this I'm using `segmented` and `tidyr` packages. My main objective is to build another data frame with all the data from the piecewise linear regressions (slopes, intercepts and R²)

So far I've been able to do this for R² and intercepts. However, the slope has been the hardest part and that's why I'm here asking for your help. The results provided by the `segmented` package are in the form of lists, and the most complex list is precisely the list of slopes, which is as follows (**in the MWE I present how this list was built. Here it is for illustrative purposes only)**:

```
> Segmented.values$slopes
$x
        Est. St.Err. t value CI(95%).l CI(95%).u
slope1  1.00 0.10206  9.7980   0.56086   1.43910
slope2 -0.05 0.10206 -0.4899  -0.48914   0.38914

$x
        Est.  St.Err. t value CI(95%).l CI(95%).u
slope1  2.00 0.061237 32.6600   1.73650   2.26350
slope2 -0.05 0.061237 -0.8165  -0.31348   0.21348
```

From this list I just want to get the values of column `Est.` but despite my attempts I haven't been able to do that. My example:

```
library(segmented)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

Group <- c("A", "B")
x <- 0:5
y <- c(0, 1, 2, 2.1, 2.3, 2,
       0, 2, 4, 4.5, 4.3, 4.4)

df <- expand.grid(x = x,
                  Group = Group)

df$y <- y

Segmented.values <- df %>%
  nest_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(my.lm = list(lm(data = data,
                         formula = y ~ x)),
         my.seg = list(segmented(my.lm,
                                 seg.Z = ~ x)),
         intercepts = list(intercept(my.seg)),
         slopes = list(slope(my.seg)),
         R2 = list(summary(my.seg)$r.squared)) %>%
  unnest(c(intercepts,
           slopes,
           R2)) %>%
  select(-data,
         -my.lm,
         -my.seg,
         -intercepts,
         -R2) %>%
  unnest_wider(slopes,           
               names_sep = " ")
```

And the result is a table with all the slope data, but I only need the columns called `slopes 1` and `slopes 2` (or the `Est.` column of the list that contains these values)

```
> Segmented.values
# A tibble: 2 x 11
# Groups:   Group [2]
  Group `slopes 1` `slopes 2` `slopes 3` `slopes 4` `slopes 5` `slopes 6` `slopes 7` `slopes 8` `slopes 9` `slopes 10`
  <fct>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
1 A              1      -0.05     0.102      0.102        9.80     -0.490      0.561     -0.489       1.44       0.389
2 B              2      -0.05     0.0612     0.0612      32.7      -0.816      1.74      -0.313       2.26       0.213
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `slopes` column have many columns in addition to 'Est.' i.e.  if we extract one of the list elements

```
        Est. St.Err. t value CI(95%).l CI(95%).u
slope1  1.00 0.10206  9.7980   0.56086   1.43910
slope2 -0.05 0.10206 -0.4899  -0.48914   0.38914
```

We could extract only the 'Est.', before doing the `unnest_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(segmented)
df %>%
  nest_by(Group) %>%
  transmute(my.lm = list(lm(data = data,
                         formula = y ~ x)),
         my.seg = list(segmented(my.lm,
                                 seg.Z = ~ x)),
         intercepts = list(intercept(my.seg)),
         slopes = list(slope(my.seg)),
         R2 = list(summary(my.seg)$r.squared)) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    select(Group, slopes) %>% 
    unnest(slopes) %>%
    mutate(slopes = map(slopes, ~ .x[, "Est."])) %>% # get the 'Est.' column
    unnest_wider(slopes)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Group slope1 slope2
  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A          1  -0.05
2 B          2  -0.05
```